# How to extract array from $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, post

I am receiving POST data from a form that is an array along with a few other fields. I need to take the array data only and pass it along in a post request of my own to a backend server as json.

The $_POST data looks like this:

```
Array (
    [smsgte_submit] => Y 
    [alias] => Array (
        [1] => Array ( 
            [name] => mywife
            [number] => 6135552001
            [ssid] => 1 )
        [2] => Array (
            [name] => daughter
            [number] => 6135553001
            [ssid] => ) 
     )
)
```

I only want to capture the alias entries and encode them in json.

I was successful in encoding the entire $_POST array into json with:

```
$data['jsonpost'] = json_encode($_POST);
```

which encoded the array as expected, however, I only want the alias array, so I tried the following:

```
$data['jsonpost'] = json_encode($_POST['alias']);
```

That, however doesn't work, it returns null to the server. Then I tried:

```
$data['jsonpost'] = json_encode(array_filter($_POST, 'alias'));
```

But that returned null.

Maybe I need to redesign my form, but in the end, I want a json array that looks like this:

```
    {
    "alias": {
        "name":"mywife",
        "number":"6135552001",
        "ssid":"1"
    },
        "alias": {
        "name":"daughter",
        "number":"6135553001",
        "ssid":"2"
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work given what you've shown `json_encode($_POST['alias'])` however `$_POST` must not be what you show.  `print_r($_POST);` And what does _That, however, doesn't work_ mean?

Comment: I updated the post to reflect the output of `print_r($_POST);` however, other than laying it out more clearly as an array,  I don't believe anything has changed. `json_encode($_POST['alias'])` sends null to the server.

Comment: I don't think I trust you. `json_encode` returns a string or false. Checking for errors and warnings?

Comment: Can you show us the results of print_r($_POST);

Comment: The output of `print_r($_POST)` is `Array ( [smsgte_submit] => Y [alias] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [name] => mywife [number] => 6135552001 [ssid] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => daughter [number] => 6135553001 [ssid] => 2) ) )`

Comment: While debugging, I changed the code as follows: `$jsonpost = json_encode($_POST['alias']);
                print_r($jsonpost);
                $data['jsonpost'] = $jsonpost;`
Now it outputs a proper json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the following syntax should be correct:

```
$data['jsonpost'] = json_encode($_POST['alias']);
```

However, in order to get it to work, I had to split it as follows:

```
$jsonpost = json_encode($_POST['alias']);
$data['jsonpost'] = jsonpost;
```

I switched back and forth between the two options a few times, but only the second one works, at least with PHP 7.3.5.

Comment: Not sure this answer reality answers anything. You are probably overlooking a warning about `Cannot use a scalar value as an array` or `Illegal string offset` which would shed light on what you were doing and why it was wrong.

Comment: I wasn't presented any warnings.